# ParseExceptions not getting thrown for CallFunctionAsync

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I recently updated my client sdk to parse 1.6.2 for xamarin, and I noticed that ParseExceptions are no longer getting thrown properly.

When calling something like this:

```
string result = await ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<string>( "function" )
```

If that function calls response.error I get:

```
System.Net.WebException The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Raw
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:944
```

Where as in the pass it would generate a ParseException with the contents of the response.error. The WebException also does not have an inner exception to inspect.

I also thought it had something to do with my cloud code, but I find a similar problem with user login. A bad password generates this exception now:

```
System.Net.WebException The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Raw
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:944
```

A few other things were upgraded when I updated the parse sdk. I'm now using xamarin forms 2.* instead of 1.5.* and I think the mono system libraries were also updated.

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/99 - Seems to be a known issue.

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/131

Comment: Issue 131 is mine. I ended up using the REST API which does indeed return the correct errors. There is a wrapper for it here : https://github.com/aldenquimby/parse-csharp however it's not been updated for a while so I can't say how well it works now.

I rolled my own using RestSharp for basic functions without much hassle. Although more hassle than I wanted :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have an existing code base, and I wanted some fixes from the 1.6 branch. I will have to downgrade if they don't post a build soon.